# Validate uniqueness of both ids in a join table

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, validation, join

I have a list model which has_and_belongs_to_many postings and vice versa.

I have a join table:

```
create_table :postings_lists do |t|
  t.integer :posting_id
  t.integer :list_id
end
```

Users have many lists.
I already validate the list uniqueness for the user with:

```
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :user_id}
```

In the join table, how can I validate the uniqueness of both the :posting_id and the :list_id so that a posting can't belong to a list more than once?

I have tried adding, uniq: true to both has_and_belongs_to_manys in the models but it messes things up and I have tried added custom validations in the list model but it wasn't working.

I think the simplest thing would be just to validate both ids in the join table but I don't know if I can do that without creating a model?

Comment: Can you use a has_many :through instead?

Comment: I don't have a model and I'd rather not have to make one if I don't have to

Comment: I think the cleanest way is to use has_many :through, otherwise you're going to have to do some complicated, likely less efficient, and harder to maintain hacks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a has_many :through instead of HABTM.

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :postings
  has_many :posts, through: :postings
end

class Posting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :post

  validate :post_id, uniqueness: {scope: :list_id} 
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :postings
  has_many :lists, through: postings
end
```

Comment: I don't know what 'post' is supposed to be in your answer.

Comment: Post is your current posting - if you want to keep posting just choose any other name for it.  list_posting would work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding **uniq: true**

- Lists

has_and_belongs_to_many :postings, **uniq: true**

- Postings

has_and_belongs_to_many :lists, **uniq: true**

This causes some issues if you use things like pluck on postings because things have to be "distinct" before doing other things like "order_by" to them.

But you can work around this issue by using different queries like 'map' instead.